# Animate color of Paint object

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, paint

I am trying to animate a `Paint` object in my custom view between colors. But the animation is not working.

```
ObjectAnimator colorFade = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(mCirclePaint, "color", new ArgbEvaluator(), getColor(), 0xff000000);
              colorFade.setDuration(1500);
              colorFade.start();

            invalidate();
```

I have previously set the paints color like this:

`mCirclePaint.setColor(Color.RED);`

**UPDATE** I don't think the `Handler` makes a difference to whether it animated or not. Even without the Handler I cannot animate the paint object.

Comment: what is mCirclePaint?

Comment: @pskink It is just a Paint object for a circle.

Comment: mCirclePaint is properly animated, your problem is that invalidate is not called

Comment: @pskink I just had the same thought, but where do I need to call `invalidate()`? I currently have it in, but it is clearly in the wrong place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the solution I found:

```
ObjectAnimator    colorFade = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(mCirclePaint, "color", new ArgbEvaluator(), getColor(), mColors[randomNum]);
                  colorFade.setDuration(1500);
                colorFade.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        invalidate();

                    }


                });

                  colorFade.start();
```

Comment: where I  have to add this code, in onDraw or  in inIt() method?

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
class MyView extends View {
    private Paint mPaint;
    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mPaint = new Paint();

        ArgbEvaluator evaluator = new ArgbEvaluator();
        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(this, "color", evaluator, 0xffff0000, 0xff00ff00, 0xff0000ff);
        animator.setDuration(6000).start();
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        mPaint.setColor(color);
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPaint(mPaint);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just posted an answer myself with a Animation Listener.