# Android Canvas transition from white to red

Tags: java, android, timer, android-canvas, thread-sleep

I am trying to transition the canvas from white to red however it seems to never draw till the very end. So you cannot see the transition. I have tried a few options using Timer and other Java utilities however they always require the variables to be final which is not possible. I believe using thread sleep is the best approach however I do not get the desired output.

```
for(int i=0; i < 255; i++){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
        paint.setARGB(255,i,0,0);
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);
        invalidate();
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

As you can see the for loop will loop through 0 - 255 and sets the paint's argb accordingly. The canvas get's painted and `invalidate()` is called. There is a slight delay of 10 for the `Thread.sleep()` method.

I have not found a nice way to accomplish this in android canvas and this I think is my current implementation. For the few seconds delay there is nothing and then at the end just the final color of `argb(255,255,0,0)`. When it should be showing every color from `argb(255,0,0,0)` - `argb(255,255,0,0)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ValueAnimator` for this like below

```
class CustomView extends AnyView {

  ...

  public void setBackgroundColor(int color){
    paint.setColor(color);
    invalidate();
  }

  public void animateColorChange(int startColor, int endColor) {
   ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(startColor, endColor); 
    anim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
    anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            final int newColor = (int) animator.getAnimatedValue();
            setBackgroundColor(newColor);
        } });

    anim.start();
  }

 public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawPaint(paint);
  }
}
```

Or replace `ValueAnimator` with `ObjectAnimator`

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(paint, "color", new ArgbEvaluator(), startColor, endColor);
anim.setDuration(1500);
anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
  @Override
  public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
    invalidate();
  }
});

anim.start();
```

Comment: Look at my updated answer. Dont use invalidate() in onDraw() method. This method invokes onDraw() each time you call it

Comment: With ValueAnimator you can animate range of int, just like in your case, but it will be as animation. You can get animated value, 'i' in your case, from onAnimationUpdate method

Comment: But you dont need to animate 0..255, just read about ArgbEvaluator that was created to animate changes between two colors

Comment: I think there are some syntax issues and that in this.

Comment: your animator.getAnimatedValue(); should be anim.getAnimatedValue();

Comment: Also I tried your solution like this but it crashed:  animateColorChange(Color.WHITE, Color.RED);
canvas.drawPaint(backgroundPaint);

Comment: Also  ValueAnimator anim has to be  final ValueAnimator anim, says Android Studio. Thanks again for the help. I think this is a great solution if it works :)

Comment: Yea, it has. Sorry, but I'm writing from iPad and there could be bugs in my code, but trust me, you could not find better solution )

Comment: Here is my example of ValueAnimator with ArgbEvaluator https://youtu.be/mQX6WuTdkb4

Comment: I think something is missing? it stays at white.

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19891028 It is similar to mine, but using ObjectAnimator instead of ValueAnimator

Comment: I am just confused where would I call animatecolorChange? If i call it in the onDraw then it always starts off as white. Which i think is the issue i am facing. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: You should call it from your activity or fragment after it was resumed, if you call it earlier user may not see an animation

Comment: I do not think that is possible. I set the contentView to the canvas

Comment: That is hard to help you without any code. This solution should work. You need now to find out when and where to call animated background change. Good luck at your research.

Comment: It works! Beautiful solution. I placed the call outside the draw in an intersection i had and added a duration since the animation is too fast. I will need to research more into these Animation, and valueAnimator. Thanks a lot for continued feedback in comments.